# Coderush plugin not generating correct try catch end try block

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, coderush, dxcore

We've created a little plugin to add a block of xml comment and create a try-catch to a function. (we simply add this to each and every function we write)
But with the latest devexpress update I'm having a problem with the following code.

```
Private Sub cpAddComment_Apply(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal ea As DevExpress.CodeRush.Core.ApplyContentEventArgs) Handles cpAddXMLCommentAndTryCatch.Apply
    ' create elementbuilder and add current code to it
    Dim objMethod As New Method
    objMethod = objOldMethod.Clone()
    objElementBuilder.AddStatement(Nothing, objMethod)

    ' add try
    Dim objTry As DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.Try = objElementBuilder.AddTry(objMethod)
    Dim objCatch As DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.Catch = objElementBuilder.AddCatch(objMethod, "Exception", "ex")

    ' add exception
    Dim strErrorString As String = """Error in " + objMethod.Location + """, ex"
    Dim objThrow As New DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.Throw

    Dim objException As New DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.TypeReferenceExpression("Exception")
    Dim objExceptionString As New DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.PrimitiveExpression(strErrorString)
    Dim objNewException As New DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.ObjectCreationExpression(objException)
    objNewException.AddArgument(objExceptionString)
    objThrow.Expression = objNewException
    'objThrow.AddFooter(" ") 'This isnt working either
    objElementBuilder.AddThrow(objCatch, objThrow)


    ' substitute code
    Dim newCode As String = objElementBuilder.GenerateCode()
    ea.TextDocument.Replace(objOldMethod.Range, newCode, "Update Method", True)
end sub
```

Instead of generating a correct Try-catch block it generates the following incorrect code:

```
    Try
    Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception("Error in test", ex)End Try
```

Strangely enough the following code seems to work(its about the same code but then for event handlers to show a messagebox instead of an exception)

```
If not CodeRush.Language.ActiveExtension.DotNetLanguageType = DotNetLanguageType.CSharp Then
    Dim objExceptionString As New DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.PrimitiveExpression("Messagebox.Show(" + strErrorString + ")" + vbCrLf)
    objElementBuilder.AddStatement(objCatch, objExceptionString)
Else
```

This problem exists in Vb.Net but in C# the brackets are correctly placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue and registered it in DevExpress Support Center. You are welcome to track its status [here](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=B187106). Once it is fixed, you can request a build containing the fix from the Support Team at support @ devexpress.com. For now, as a work-around, you can replace this line of code:

```
objThrow.Expression = objNewException
```

into this:

```
objThrow.Expression = New SnippetExpression(CodeRush.Language.GenerateExpressionCode(objNewException) + vbCrLf)
```

This will generate the try/catch block correctly in Visual Basic.

Comment: Since we had a generic plug generating code for C# and Vb.Net I've added a condition.
CodeRush.Language.ActiveExtension.DotNetLanguageType <> DotNetLanguageType.CSharp

Comment: You can also use the CodeRush.Language.IsCSharp property.